# React component does not call connect redux function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a weird problem with the connection of the component and redux store.
While I have 2 component(siblings) one can connect to redux store (Pets.js) the other does not(FeedList.js)

I will try to explain as much as I can.

From top-to-bottom struct here is my project.

App.js:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import { Provider as AlertProvider } from "react-alert";
import AlertTemplate from "react-alert-template-basic";

// Components
import Header from "./layout/Header";
import Dashboard from "./pets/Dashboard";
import Alerts from "./layout/Alerts";
import Login from "./accounts/Login";
import Register from "./accounts/Register";
import PrivateRoute from "./common/PrivateRoute";
import MainFeed from "./feed/MainFeed";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "../store";
import { loadUser } from "../actions/auth";

const alertOptions = {
  timeout: 3000,
  position: "top center",
};

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(loadUser);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
          <Router>
            <Fragment>
              <Header />
              <Alerts />
              <div className="container">
                <Switch>
                  <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                  <PrivateRoute
                    exact
                    path="/feed"
                    component={MainFeed}
                    {...store}
                  />
                  <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
                  <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </Fragment>
          </Router>
        </AlertProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
// ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

My custom Route Component is the PrivateRoute where I pass the props to other comps.

PrivateRoute.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => {
      if (auth.isLoading) {
        return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
      } else if (!auth.isAuthenticated) {
        return <Redirect to="/login" />;
      } else {
        console.log(props);
        return <Component {...props} />;
      }
    }}
  />
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, { pure: false })(
  PrivateRoute
);
```

Ok here comes the weird part of the problem in the Dashboard component which renders the Pets component everything is fine and it connects to the store.

Dashboard.js:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import Form from "./Form";
import Pets from "./Pets";

export default function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Form />
      <Pets />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Pets.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { getPets, deletePet, getAllPets } from "../../actions/pets";

import UserPetsStyle from "../../style/LayoutStyle";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";

import {
  Paper,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
} from "@material-ui/core";

export class Pets extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    pets: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    getPets: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    deletePet: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    getAllPets: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.getPets();
  }

  render() {
    const classes = UserPetsStyle;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <h2>Pets</h2>
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell align="right">ID</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Name</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Race</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Create At</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Actions</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {this.props.pets.map((pet) => (
                <TableRow key={pet.id}>
                  <TableCell align="right">{pet.id}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{pet.name}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{pet.race}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{pet.created_at}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">
                    <DeleteIcon
                      onClick={this.props.deletePet.bind(this, pet.id)}
                      className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                    />
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  pets: state.pets.pets,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPets, deletePet, getAllPets })(
  Pets
);
```

While my MainFeed/FeedList does not even call the connect function.

MainFeed.js:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { FeedList } from "../feed/FeedList";

export default function MainFeed() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <FeedList />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

FeedList.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import UserPetsStyle from "../../style/LayoutStyle";

import { getAllPets } from "../../actions/pets";
import {
  Paper,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
} from "@material-ui/core";

export class FeedList extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    pets: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    getAllPets: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this);
    // this.props.getAllPets();
  }

  render() {
    const classes = UserPetsStyle;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <h2>Pets</h2>
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell align="right">ID</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Name</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Race</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Create At</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Actions</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {/* {this.props.pets.map((pet) => (
                <TableRow key={pet.id}>
                  <TableCell align="right">{pet.id}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{pet.name}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{pet.race}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{pet.created_at}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right"></TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))} */}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    pets: state.pets.pets,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getAllPets })(FeedList);
```

So any ideas?

To help you further I have tried the withRouter method and the {pure:false} option at connect func but nothings seems to change.Also while using reduxDevTools and DevTools it seems like mapStateToProps is not called at FeedList.js component.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

the second argument of connect dispatch should be send like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    // dispatching plain actions
    getAllPets: () => dispatch(getAllPets())
   
  }
}
```

Comment: If you mean at the last component FeedList.js , then nothing happens.
When i console.log(this.props) in the ComponentDidMount() func the props are null
there neither the pets[] array nor the function getAllPets.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it.
The problem was that i was importing the componet  FeedaList with brackets ( {FeedList} ) while i shouldnt.